# Refactor nested API calls with RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here's what I need to refactor:

1. Call `API/GetUser`, get result, extract `user.id`, save result (`user`)
2. Call `API/GetMoreUserData/{userId}` with `id` from first call, save result (`moreData`)
3. Construct object with both results `{u: user, d: moreData }` and return it to the caller

I'm currently using nested calls to accomplish this, but I'm sure there's a better way of doing it with RxJS.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) is for.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    //mock implementation, probably would be an HTTP get
    return of({ id: 42 });
  }

  getMoreUserData(id: number): Observable<any> {
    //mock implementation, probably would be an HTTP get
    return of({ username: 'batman', id: id });
  }

  getAllTheUserData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.getUser().pipe(
      switchMap((userResp) => {
        const userId = userResp.id;

        return this.getMoreUserData(userId).pipe(
          map((moreUserResp) => {
            //spread operator to combine to two objects
            return {
              ...userResp,
              ...moreUserResp,
            };
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6bfhhj?file=src/app/user.service.ts) demonstrating the service and it's usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe and switchMap, here is a random example:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(                            //params returns an observable
      switchMap(({id}) => this.buyerService.getDetails(id)) //getDetails returns an observable
    )
    .subscribe(h => {
      console.log(h)
}
```